# MVC2 app modifying posted-back parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building a blog engine inside an MVC2 app.

The URL for each post contains the title of the URL. When the title has a question mark, the question mark quite naturally appears in the URL, but when the request arrives at the controller, the question mark has been removed.

Presumably this is some security measure, but in this situation it's causing a problem.

Can anyone tell me how to work around this?

The format of the URL is

```
http://www.mydomain.com/posts/title-with-question-mark?/
```

Comment: That's how querystrings work.

Comment: There is no query-string involved here. I've updated the post to show the format of the URL. I can understand that the question mark would appear to the routing engine as the start of an empty query-string, but it's not, and isn't there a way to include the question mark?

Comment: There is a query string involved... you just don't realize it. That's what the question mark is causing.

Comment: Short answer is no. There isn't a way to make your url look like that. The question mark is a special character and can't be used for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark marks the beginning of the querystring and is not part of the path.

You need to URL-encode it.

Comment: Even when I replace the question mark with &#63; MVC changes this to a straightforward textual "?" in the markup.

Comment: Ok, Server.UrlPathEncode isn't recognised, but I can use HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode() - in fact I was using this already. Unfortunately that doesn't do anything to the question mark in terms of encoding. However, I also tried HttpUtility.UrlEncode() which does encode the question mark, but if I then click on the link I get "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)".